# Compact and Weierstrass

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

If $f:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow{\mathbb{R}}$  :

$f(x)=0 $ , if  $x=1$ and $f(x)=\dfrac{1}{x-1}$ if $x>1$

(i) Proof $ f(\mathbb{N})$ is a compact set.

(ii) Is Weierstrass's theorem  applicable?
$f^{-1}:f(\mathbb{N})\rightarrow{\mathbb{N}}$

Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried? For $(i)$, use Heine-Borel. Regarding $(ii)$, Weierstrass had a lot of theorems, which one do you mean?

Comment: Applicable to what? $f$ or $f^{-1}$?

Comment: is for $f^{-1}$

Answer (score 1):

See that the set $f(\Bbb N)$ is closed and bounded thus conclude that it is compact. To see boundedness of $f(\Bbb N)$ see that $f(x) \leq 1 $ forall $x \in \Bbb N$.

$f(\Bbb N) = \{0,1,1/2,1/3, \cdots\}$. It is easy to see that $f(\Bbb N)$ is a closed set in $\Bbb R$ since $0$ is the only limit point of the set and it is in the set.

Comment: How proof closed?

Comment: you're right thanks.

Comment: Thanks for accepting my answer

Comment: I have not understand your question of part 2